# How do I rename and map column to multi index header and set another column as index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to change a dataset from this table to one that is multi indexed header of area and region code and an index of age of district. So far, tried using transpose and creating multi headers but I keep getting NA values. Any help would be appreciated!

Input:

| Area Code | Region Code | Age of District | Amount of crime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | B | 0 - 2 years | 2 |
| D | A | 2 - 4 years | 5 |

Expected output:

| Region Code | B | A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Area Code | C | D |
| Age of District | Amount of crime | Amount of crime |
| 0 - 2 years | 2 | NA |
| 2 - 4 years | NA | 5 |

Any indication of how to do it or maybe a better way to structure would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say **df** is your data frame, simply use df.transpose to get transposed data

```
df_New = df.T.reset_index()
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not exactly transposing, you want to maintain your columns 'age of district' as a new index